# laravel 7 store multiple values in different row and also another tables in different row

Tags: php, laravel

**help me? I want to input multiple value and store in database with different row. with some other values inset in anther 2 different  tables at same time. im not able to code controller store part i spent 3days help me **

example :

In input form, to "table name"( Purchases )

```
    |   product   quantity     price     manufacturer    |
    |     a           1         12$           xyz        |
    |     b           2         1$             x         |
    |     c           10        10$            y         |
```

also insert selected fled 'product' 'quantity' 'price' this value to  "table name"( bill_products)

```
    |   product   quantity     price    |
    |    a           1         12$      |
    |    b           2         1$       |
    |    c           10        10$      |
```

also insert selected fled 'product' 'quantity'  this value to  "table name"( item_lists)

```
    |   product   quantity     |
    |    a           1         |
    |    b           2         |
    |    c           10        |
```

This is my view (purchase\purchase-entry.blade.php)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">PURCHASE FORM</div>

                <div class="card-body">
            
                @if (Session::has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">{!! Session::get('success') !!}</div>
                @endif
                @if (Session::has('failure'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{!! Session::get('failure') !!}</div>
                @endif
                         
    <form method="POST"   action="{{route('purchasesave')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @csrf
<div class="form-row">

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label >product NAME</label>
      <input type="text"  name="product[]"  placeholder="product" value="" required >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label >quantity</label>
      <input type="text"  name="quantity[]"  placeholder="quantity" value="" required >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label >price</label>
      <input type="text"  name="price[]"  placeholder=price" value="" required >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label >manufacturer</label>
      <input type="text"  name="manufacturer[]"  placeholder="manufacturer" value="" required >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

This is my controller (PurchaseController.php) and I have 3 model (Purchase , Bill_product and Item_list )

```
public function purchasesave(Request $request)
   {

   }
```

this is route part

```
Route::post('purchasesave', 'PurchaseController@purchasesave')->name('purchasesave');
```

Comment: Please add the route code also if possible

Comment: @Amit Patel route code updated

Comment: @Amit Patel route code updated please help me

Comment: Remove the enctype="multipart/form-data" if you have no file to upload in the form and run your code

Comment: @Amit Patel ok i removed enctype="multipart/form-data" can you code controller part please

Comment: ok i will but first you add your code which you tried in controller

Comment: @Amit Patel honesty i tell you actually i dont know how to pass multiple values passing in controller, please help me i am witting for your help

Comment: @user12931578 Then you didn't read any documentation or did any research effort by yourself. It is not acceptable that someone should write your whole codebase

Comment: @Aless55 i did research. if i post my controller code it will confuse my  codes for everyone  so i  was not updated controller , if you have solution for this please help, #motivate if anyone learning something new if you have knowledge share with everyone. please

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing an array for each attribute, you will be able to iterate over it. Please make sure to properly valdiate your data.
Afterwards you can simply get the items of each array at the same index.
So for example all items at index 0 because they belong together.

```
public function purchasesave(Request $request)
   {
     //insert your validation here
    
     foreach($request->product as $k => $p){
       Pruchases::create([
           'product' => $request['product'][$k],
           'quantity' => $request['quantity'][$k],
           'price' => $request['price'][$k],
           'manufacturer' => $request['manufacturer'][$k],
       ]);

       BillProduct::create([
           'product' => $request['product'][$k],
           'quantity' => $request['quantity'][$k],
           'price' => $request['price'][$k],
       ]);
 
       ItemList::create([
           'product' => $request['product'][$k],
           'quantity' => $request['quantity'][$k],
       ]);
     }
   }
```

If you don't use models you can simply replace the statements by using `DB` and `insert()`, to insert the data into your DB.

Comment: Thank you For your help. every thing working fine except ItemList not updating perfectly it just storing one itme every time i submitting a form. my form passing more then 2 items every submission  but it storing one value.

Comment: @user12931578 hmm that is strange, if the other 2 work, then the third one should also work. I changed `ItemList()` to `ItemList` it was a typo by me, maybe this resolves the problem.

Comment: if i use this  ItemList() it showing error like this, Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\ItemList().  if i use ItemList its storing only one value

Comment: @user12931578 yes then thats not the problem. Are you sure that the closing `}` is after all create statements?

Comment: BillProduct and ItemList also not storing multiple values yes i checked } closed

Comment: @Aless55 BillProduct and ItemList also not storing multiple values. ?

Comment: how does your request look like can you dd($request->all)

Comment: @Aless55 request coming in array i check it

Comment: did you specify the right fillable attributes in your models? @user12931578

Comment: @Aless55 yes i checked models every fillable attributes every thing ok

Comment: Im running out of ideas. Did you implement it exactly the same? Does your arrays have more than 1 element?

Comment: @Aless55 yes did exactly the same , check this code it worked but it not work at same time value store . public function purchasesave(Request $request)
   {

    $input = $request->all();

for($i=0; $i<= count($input['quantity']); $i++) {

  if(empty($input['quantity'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['quantity'][$i])) continue;

  $data = [ 
    'product' => $input['product'][$i],
    'quantity' => $input['quantity'][$i],
    'MRP_rate' => $input['MRP_rate'][$i],  
    'price' => $input['price'][$i],  
 
    'qty' => intval($input['qty'][$i])
  ];

  Pruchases::create($data);

}

Comment: @user12931578 I only see that you are createing a new Purchase, where are the other 2 create statements?

Comment: @Aless55 i just showing this code for new idea to fix yor answer code

Comment: what if the tables have relations between them, how to pass the ID of `Pruchase` to `BillProduct` on creation !?